# How to split a string in two and store it in a field

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a class of fields that is like the following:

```
public class EmployeeInformationNames {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

If I have a string

```
String str = "First Name: George\nLast Name: Brown";
```

I want to parse the string and store it in a map such that

```
Map<String, String> myMap  = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Where my key would be George and my value would be Brown.

I am not to sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Why would you want to store it in a `Map` when you can put it in a `EmployeeInformationNames` instance?

Comment: I am creating a timesheet program where I am going to have multiple people inputting their data. I want to organize the data in a way that if the user enters their first name then I can retreive their last name. I eventually would like to make my value a set that cotnains last name, address, birthday etc. But for now I want to get the basics. I was thinking of doing instances but if I have say 10000 users then I would have to create 1000 instances right? So I decided to write each person to a file then read it into a map so that my map contains a way of retrieving each persons information

Comment: If you read this string from a file, you might consider using the class `Properties`, which can do the parsing for you. You'd call `Properties person = Properties.load(...)` and then `person.getProperty("First Name")`...

Comment: would using a property work if I were to parse more fields, and would a property group together my information, such as person1 and their attributes and person2 and their attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
String[] parsedInput = str.split("\n");
String firstName = parsedInput[0].split(": ")[1];
String lastName = parsedInput[1].split(": ")[1];
myMap.put(firstName,lastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

A regex approach might include:

First extracting the first and last name with:

```
String str = "First Name: George\nLast Name: Brown";
Pattern namePat = Pattern.compile("Name: (\\w+)");
Matcher nameMatcher = namePat.matcher(str);
nameMatcher.find();
String firstName = nameMatcher.group(1);
nameMatcher.find();
String lastName = nameMatcher.group(1);
```

Then adding the first and last name to the `HashMap` with:

```
myMap.put(firstName, lastName);
```

Java Regex Resource (if interested):

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Split the input string(s) with suitable regular expressions,

```
String str = "First Name: George\nLast Name: Brown";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?:\\s*(\\w+)\\s*\n.*?:\\s*(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("matcher group 1: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("matcher group 2: " + matcher.group(2));

    map[matcher.group(1)] = matcher.group(2);
}
```